# How to maintain JSON's order in Groovy's JsonSlurper?

Tags: java, json, groovy

I am reading a simple JSON....

```
{"A":0,"B":0,"C":2,"D":0,"F":5}
```

into a map using JsonSlurper in Groovy...

```
Map gradeDistributon = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonString)
```

But when iterating over this map with a closure..

```
gradeDistributon.each{ entry ->   
     println "From map got key ${entry.key}"
```

I am seeing the keys are not in the order they were in the original JSON, for example 'C' comes first. I think this is because Map does not maintain insertion order in Java. Is there a way I can keep the order of the original JSON?

If it means reading the JSON in a different way (instead of into a Map with JsonSlurper) then I am fine with that if you can show me how.

Comment: JSON is by definition an unordered collection. Why you need order?

Comment: @Opal, I am printing this out in a report on the front end and they want to see the counts for grade 'A' first.

Comment: So just sort it by grades.

Answer (score 2):

You can set JVM system property `jdk.map.althashing.threshold` to make `JsonSlurper` to use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of `TreeMap` as the internal `Map` implementation, e.g. `-Djdk.map.althashing.threshold=512`.

The reason is in [source code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/4993b10737881b2491c2daa01526fb15dd889ac5/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.java#L114) of `groovy.json.internal.LazyMap` used by `JsonSlurper`.

```
private static final String JDK_MAP_ALTHASHING_SYSPROP = System.getProperty("jdk.map.althashing.threshold");

private void buildIfNeeded() {  
    if (map == null) {
        /** added to avoid hash collision attack. */
        if (Sys.is1_7OrLater() && JDK_MAP_ALTHASHING_SYSPROP != null) {
            map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(size, 0.01f);
        } else {
            map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note this solution should be used as a hack as it depends on Groovy's internal implementation details. So this behavior may change in future version of Groovy.

See my [blog post](http://midgetontoes.com/properties-ordering-of-groovy-jsonslurper-parsing/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your behaviour with groovy 2.4.5 but you can try using LinkedHashMap (allow to iterate over map keys maintaining the order in which the entries were inserted):

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonText = '''
{"A":0,"B":0,"C":2,"D":0,"F":5,"G":7,"H":9}
'''

LinkedHashMap json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)
json.each{ entry ->
  println "${entry.key}"
}
```

**NOTE**: as stated by @XenoN the JsonSlurper() sort the json keys during the parsing process so independently of the input order (ie. `{"H":0,"B":0,"A":2,"D":0,"G":5,"F":7,"C":9}`) the output of JsonSlurper will be always: `{"A":2,"B":0,"C":9,"D":0,"F":7,"G":5,"H":0}`.

Using the *LinkedHashMap* instead of a HashMap we preserve the order given by JsonSlurper.

Comment: You can't reproduce it. because JsonSlurper orders it by asc. look at your example a b c ?

Comment: @XenoN: you're right, the input example i've used is masking the JsonSlurper sorting behaviour, but the guy whose ask the question has the opposite problem: json ends to be not sorted alphabetically at the end. Using a LinkedHashMap we can then guarantee to maintain the sort order given by JsonSlurper

Comment: Yep. But he uses dummy data as example and his real code is different i bet. He thinks map is messing up his order. Actually Slurper is. That's why you couldn't reproduce it again

Comment: I did face exact same problem when i try to use mongodb $nearSphere with $maxDistance. In my case constraints should be exact same order in order to make correct result.

Comment: And i end up reordering map after parsing.

Comment: @XenoN: i understand your point and you're right but in this case the letters of the examples are not fakes (user3223841 specify it in the comment under his question): they are actually grades, and the desired output is sorted alphabetically (as they are in the beginnings as he stated). He says the results has lost the alphabetical order somehow

Comment: @XenoN: thank you anyhow to pointing out that JsonSlurper sort the json alphabetically. It's a missing piece of the picture!

Answer (score 1):

So it was just a matter of sorting the keys after JsonSlurper built the Map, for that I just read into a TreeMap which sorts the keys by default..

```
TreeMap gradeDistributon = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonString)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, i can't reproduce your behaviour no even shuffling the json (seems like JsonSlurper sort elements by default). What version of groovy do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I run the same code on Groovy 2.4.x and on 3.0.x.
On 2.4 the order is preserved,but on 3.0 is sorted asc by default.

Answer (score 1):

use the JsonSluperClassic().parse() instead it will preserve the order